# Pull out a div from the bottom

Tags: html, jquery-animate, slide

I have this code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/3/)

Quite simply, I want to pull it out from the bottom, on a fixed size page (1920x1080), I have this sample working to pull from the right edge, but not sure how to move it to the bottom.

Many thanks if you can help

HTML

```
<div id="slideout">
    <div id="slidecontent">
        Yar, there be dragonns herre!
    </div>
    <div id="clickme">
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'}, {queue: false, duration: 500});
    });
});
```

Style:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 45%;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 20px
}

#clickme {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #ff0000;
}

#slidecontent {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the following [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yHPTv/889/)..

Basically I copied and pasted your code and manipulated using `bottom` positioning. that way you will be able to see the differences between the two.. both in CSS and JS. it is essentially the same logic as the code you posted.

Note that the body now has `overflow:hidden;` instead of `overflow-x:hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

To move it to the bottom, simply make a small change to your CSS.

```
#slideout {
    background: #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 280px;
    height: 80px;
    bottom: 50px;
    right:-280px;
    padding-left: 20px
}
```